# Derivative of inverse of summation wrt matrix

Tags: derivatives, inverse, matrix-calculus

Consider the matrix equation $l=\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M \left(\mathbf M^\top \mathbf M+\mathbf I\right)^{-1}\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x$ and we need to find the derivative wrt matrix $\mathbf M$.

My idea was to use the chain rule and rewrite the inverse as $\mathbf D=\left(\mathbf M^\top \mathbf M+\mathbf I\right)^{-1}$. Then using eq. 82 of matrix cookbook
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf M}\left[\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M \mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\right]=\mathbf D^\top\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top+\mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top = 2\mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top$

Then the derivative of $\mathbf D$:
$\frac{\partial\mathbf D}{\partial \mathbf M}=-\mathbf D2\mathbf M\mathbf D$, where the $2\mathbf M$ are the derivative of $\mathbf M^\top \mathbf M+\mathbf I$

Combining: $\frac{\partial l}{\partial \mathbf M}=\left[2\mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top\right]^\top\left[-\mathbf D2\mathbf M\mathbf D\right]=-4\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M \mathbf D\mathbf D\mathbf M\mathbf D$

I know that this is not correct but I can't see where my mistake is. Perhaps in the calculations of the derivative of the inverse?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf M}\left[\mathbf x^\top\mathbf M \mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\right]=\mathbf D^\top\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top+\mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top = 2\mathbf D\mathbf M^\top\mathbf x\mathbf x^\top$ can be used only when $\mathbf D$ is not related to $\mathbf M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\l{\ell} \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\op{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$For typing convenience, define the symmetric matrix
$$X=xx^T$$
and the Frobenius $(:)$ product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
Then invoke the well-known rule for differentiating matrix inverses
$$\eqalign{
 D &= \LR{M^TM+I}^{-1} \\ 
dD &= -\LR{D\:\c{dD^{-1}}D} \;=\; -D\CLR{dM^TM+M^TdM}D
}$$
Now calculate the gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\l &= X:MDM^T \\
d\l
 &= X:\LR{\c{dM}\,DM^T + MD\,\c{dM^T} + M\,\c{dD}\,M^T} \\
 &= XMD:\c{dM} + DM^TX:\c{dM^T} + M^TXM:\c{dD} \\
 &= 2XMD:\c{dM} - M^TXM:\c{D\CLR{dM^TM+M^TdM}D} \\
 &= 2XMD:\c{dM} - 2DM^TXMD:\CLR{M^TdM} \\
 &= 2\LR{XMD - MDM^TXMD}:\c{dM} \\
 &= 2\LR{I - MDM^T}XMD:\c{dM} \\
\grad{\l}{M} &= 2\LR{I - MDM^T}XMD \\
}$$
$\sf NB\!:$ Since $(D,X)$ are symmetric, I have omitted their transposes in several of the steps above.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I was hoping for an answer from you specifically, but I couldn't hope for such a quick reply!